# Using Sencha Architect 3 with visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, sencha-architect

I am about to make a new project, where the frontend has to be using Extjs and the backend has to be using C#. I need some kind of MVC structure. As I am completely new to Extjs and Sencha, I was wondering if it was possible to use sencha architect 3 along with visual studio, such that I am able to write the backend code in Visual Studio 2012 and the frontend code in sencha arctitecture.

Basicly I am interrested in article or help in generel about how I get the two applications to interact.

I hope you can help, thanks in advance!

Regards

Magnus D. Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development of the backend and the frontend are quite independent.

The MVC structure for ExtJs is defined very clearly. For this study the docs. Start [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture), and then read the *Tutorials* section (*App Architecture Part 1-3*). Stick as much as you can to the recommandations. Also try out `sencha cmd` to build your apps.

The interaction between ExtJs and the backend is defined in the [`proxy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy) settings you are using. Basicly, ExtJs is sending a ajax request (maybe GET, POST or RESTful) to the backend, and receives the data in JSON encoded form.